# escape % in iOS to write sql

Tags: ios, sql

I want to write sql query in NSString, the query is:

```
WHERE fa_name LIKE '%anyValue%'
```

I wrote the following code

```
NSString *whereFamilyName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"fa_name LIKE '\%%@\%'", typedFamilyName];
```

but it doesn't escape the % and the output is:

```
fa_name LIKE '%@'
```

Comment: There are 2 % sign in youe string(fa_name LIKE '\%%@\%). Try it again by removing 1 % sign.Somthing like this:-
fa_name LIKE '\%@\%

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To Escape a `%` simply write two `%%`.

`NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"fa_name LIKE '%%%@%%'", @"val"];`